# Add choice All to SXA checklist filter

Tags: sxa, content-search

I have a SXA checklist filter, let's say it has 10 choices. I want to select and filter by them "all". So I want to add a choice which filter by them all and name it : "All".

Is there a way to do this (ootb) with the Filter Checklist component?

Comment: Could you describe your need in more detail? Perhaps add also some screenshots so it's obvious where you want to add "All" as option

Comment: I have a SXA checklist filter, let's say it have 10 choices, I want to select and filter by them all, So I want to add a choice which filter by them all and name it : "All"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such functionality is not available out of the box. But there is plenty of ways to achieve this. Start of investigating `component-search-results-filter.js` file. You could for example:

- modify rendering view with additional checkbox and implement `checked` event logic as a separate function of Backbone view
- dynamically inject checkbox in the `api.init` function (after view initialization) and add function out of the view scope to find and check all checkbox in the filter
- and a few more approaches...

Don't wait for a ready solution, ask questions to solve the problems not to copy and paste particular solution. I bet you've never opened `component-search-results-filter.js`.

Comment: I think I was just not specific enough, I wanted to know if there is an out-of-the-box solution for it, I did it by jQuery and it worked, Thank you.